# Последовательный запуск контейнеров в docker-compose.yml

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Использую `docker-compose.yml` для запуска нескольких контейнеров и возникла проблема, что `RabbitMQ` запускается после `Сelery` (очередь из задач для Python) и из этого вопрос:

Как можно запустить сначала `контейнер #1`, а когда он запуститься уже запускать `контейнер #2`?

Comment: боюсь, только принудительным ожиданием необходимого сервиса в entrypoint

Comment: @etki спасибо, сейчас так и есть, `Сelery` ждет когда получиться подключиться к `RabbitMQ`, но есть ощущение что это неправильное решение.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Нужно ожидать пока сервис не поднимется. Положи [wait-for](https://github.com/eficode/wait-for/blob/master/wait-for) в container.

```
celery:
   depends_on:
     - rabbitmq # старт после старта контейнера rabbitmq
   command: sh -c './wait-for host:5432 -- cmd' # ожидаем
```

Comment: спасибо, но думаю стоит это решать на уровне docker'a и приложения

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/

Ключевое слово - depends_on.
Так будет указано что контейнер зависит от другого и их запуск будет в определенном порядке.

Comment: Я как понимаю у контейнера нет фазы запускаться и depends_on особо не чего не изменит? 
Просто использую depends_on его но celery стартует уже тогда когда RabbitMQ еще не запустился

Comment: не так, celery запустился после запуска container RabbitMQ.

Comment: @AfsmNGhr но запуск контейнера с кроликом != запуску кролика внутри этого контейнера, соответственно пинговать кроля, возможно, и лучшая идея.